# Text with different color from colored square inside canvas rectangle

Tags: javascript, canvas

May be is something easy but is it possible to make this green text `Text 1` black in order to be visible above green square?

```js
    var c = document.getElementById("canva");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "20px Arial black";
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(60,60,80,80);
    ctx.fillText("Text 2",120,130);
    ctx.strokeText("Text 1",55,50);
```

```html
<canvas id="canva" width="200" height="200" style="border:3px dotted red; border-radius: 5px;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text 1` is already black but it's just a stroke, not a fill. You can change the fill colour (of `Text 2`) by resetting the `fillStyle` after drawing the box but before setting the text:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canva");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "20px Arial black";
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(60,60,80,80);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillText("Text 2",120,130);
    ctx.strokeText("Text 1",55,50);
```

```html
<canvas id="canva" width="200" height="200" style="border:3px dotted red; border-radius: 5px;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
<script>
 var c = document.getElementById("canva");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "20px Arial black";
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(60,60,80,80);

    ctx.strokeText("Text 2",120,130);

    ctx.strokeText("Text 1",55,50);
</script>
```